# VectorstoreIndexCreator no response (Python3)

Tags: python, openai-api, py-langchain

Does anyone encounter the case that Vectorstoreindexcreator not responding? It doesnt going to the next line to execute and also not enter to the exception. Actually it runs well on my local window 11 Pro. The case occur when I run on window server 2019. I use the directory loader "index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders([loader])". Thank you.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You should edit the question and put the code there - please read the link that @D.L suggested about asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

I could see the error message after I have a deep dive to its open code. The error is

> TP_NUM_C_BUFS too small: 50

and the following post helped me solve the problem. I needed to install 2 python dependencies for the unstructured data loading [Unstructured URL Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76247540/loading-data-using-unstructuredurlloader-of-langchain-halts-with-tp-num-c-buf).

pip install python-magic python-magic-bin

pip install tabulate pdf2image pytesseract

Comment: Please don't post links as answers, they tend to break. Instead summarise how the link helped (i.e. explain what the dependencies were).